# How to print a user output by a sentence using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary in python as follows:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

I have so far run the following code in Python 3:

```
for key, value in dict1.items() :   
    print (key* value,end='')
```

This gives me the output: `cccbba`

My question is how to print out-

```
Your answer : cccba.
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

print ("Your answer : ",end='')

for key, value in dict1.items() :   
    print (key* value,end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really get to grips with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> print("Your answer: {0}".format("".join([k * v for k, v 
                                             in dict1.items()])))
Your answer: acccbb
```